# Saving state of webpage with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a card game with node.js as the server , and i'm using web sockets (socket.io) to transfer the data from server to client .

so after the cards are dealt i want if someone refreshes the page he can see the current state of the game , in my case he just see nothing the cards are not dealt and there are no players . so is there some way to save the state of the game whenever a player refreshes the pages he can see all the changes that happen to the html page .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do it is to have the actual game state on the server. That way, when the user reloads the page, the page simply requests the state back from the server. This basically means that the game is actually on the server, and your clients are merely "remote controls" to the game on the server.

Another way is to save the state locally, using local storage. However, there could have been changes between the last time the user was on the game and during his return (like a card dealt, or a card drawn, a card passed etc.).

You can even use both. Where you read the local storage for the state first. That way, you have your hand state before you left. You can then request the server for the changes, and animate the game accordingly.

Comment: any ideas how to save the actual game state on the server ??

Comment: @ziz194 Some storage mechanism, like databases or plain in-memory storages like arrays.

Comment: i searched a lot but i don't seem to find a storage mechanism that can store the whole webpage state (with css3 and jQuery modification )

Comment: @ziz194 That's where you missed. You don't save *the page*. You just save the *state of the page*. Store data, sequence of events, and other indicators. You can then reconstruct the CSS and DOM manipulations on the spot. Think of it like chess. You store the mathematical representation of the moves. To arrive to state `n` as well as get everything that happened from start to `n`, you parse the sequence.

Comment: but i don't want the user to see everthing "Re-animating" when he reconnect it will take some time to see everything moving and changing to its state

Comment: @ziz194 I never said displaying the reconstruction was required. You *parse* the data to reconstruct what happened. Reanimating is optional.